# How to auto resize tableview height + stackview

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to implement this feature:

Show title, description and image in each cell of a tableview.
However, the image could be nil.
Requirement is:

1. When image is nil, auto expand the label to fit the whole cell
2. Tableview cell height should be adjusted automatically based on the description label.
3. Need to use stackView

I did this programmatically:

1. Set this is tableview:

   ```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
   ```
2. Create 2 Stackviews: one for labels, one for labels + image:

```
    let contentStack: UIStackView = {
        var view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .horizontal
        view.spacing = 16
        view.distribution = .equalSpacing
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        return view }()
    
    let labelStack: UIStackView = {
        var view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 5
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.distribution = .fillProportionally
        return view }()
```

3. Use autolayout to setup the constraints:

```
func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(contentStack)
        labelStack.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        labelStack.addArrangedSubview(descriptionLable)
        contentStack.addArrangedSubview(labelStack)
        contentStack.addArrangedSubview(iconView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),

            contentStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            contentStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            contentStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            contentStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

However, this code doesn't auto resize the height of the tableview cells, you can see from the screenshot, cells won't expand based on the length of the labels.

What's the best way to do this with stackview?

This is what i got so far:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few changes...

Right now, your 80-pt Height image view is limiting the `contentStack` height to 80-points, so in your `contentStack` setup, use either:

```
view.alignment = .top

// or

view.alignment = .center
```

Change your `labelStack` setup to:

```
view.distribution = .fill   // NOT .fillProportionally
```

make sure you set:

```
titleLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
descriptionLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

---

**Edit**

This is how it can look with long and short descriptions, and with / without an image. The labels have a cyan background and the image views have a yellow background so you can see the frames...

[image]

If that is leaving too much top and bottom "padding" you need to adjust your top and bottom constraint constants.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried, it solved 1 issue: Now for super long contents, they show the full content by extending the cell larger. However for super short contents, the cell is still very large.

Comment: @floraliu - I edited my answer with a screen-shot of how it looks with `view.alignment = .center` ... not sure what you mean by *"the cell is still very large"*?

Comment: I set the constraints for the contentStackView to the cell for 16 on 4 sides (you can check in the code), my understanding is: If there is only description label available in the view, and it's only one line, the cell should appear as 16 top+ 16 bottom + height of the 1 line label right?

Comment: @floraliu - yes... isn't that what I've shown in the 2nd cell? If you mean you may have a cell with **no title *and* no image**, then you'll need to modifiy the code to show/hide the title label as needed.

Comment: my bad.. i forgot to hide the title ! Thank you!